# mysql query using python 3.6 (string variable is in single quotes)

Tags: mysql, quotes

I am new in python as well as mysql. I am having trouble in populating proper query statement for mysql.

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE %s"
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql,(where,))
```

where is a string variable which creates a string for **WHERE** clause; this is the point of question. When I print this variable it give the following result:
**Gender = True And IsLate = False** 
(without any quotes) but when I add this variable to the query to execute it, it adds single quotes around the string.
I used the command

```
    print(cur.statement)
```

and it prints:
**SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE 'Gender = True And IsLate = False'** 
After supplying parameter, it puts it within single quotes and query returns 0 rows.
I have worked around by concatenating the query statement and variable together and execute the string as query, that worked,

```
    sql = sql + where
    cur.execute(sql)
```

But I know that is not the professional way, as I have searched and found the professional way is to use parameterized query and use variable to store the condition(s) and supplying it at the execution of query.
Looking for advice, am I thinking the right way or otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of using parameter substitution in `cursor.execute()` is that it protects you from SQL injection. Each parameter is treated as a literal value, not substituted into the query and re-interpreted.

If you really want it to be interprted, you need to use string formatting or concatenation, as you discovered. But then you will have to be very careful in validating the input, because the user can supply extra SQL code that you may not have expected, and cause the query to malfunction.

What you should do is build the `where` string and parameter list dynamically.

```
where = []
params = []
if gender_supplied:
    where.append('gender = %s')
    params.append(gender)
if islate_supplied:
    where.append*('islate = %s')
    params.append(islate)

sql = 'select * from persons'
if where:
    query = sql + ' where ' + ' and '.join(where)
else:
    query = sql

cur.execute(query, params)
```

Comment: "Each parameter is treated as a literal value" I want to collect parameter value from user input(s) which may be 1 or more, that's why I want to concatenate all the given parameters in one string, and use it as a parameter. But in this case python adds single quotes around the string which makes the query to return 0 row (empty set). What I want is to store the string in variable so that it can be used as parameter properly (without quotes).

Comment: In the current scenario there are two conditions collected by user's input i.e.
1) Gender
2) IsLate
But they can be even more

Comment: Adding the quotes is the way it makes it a single literal value. You need a separate parameter for each condition.

Comment: I've updaed the answer to show how you can construct the query dynamically and use parameters.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! I shall give it a try and give you feedback.